# Can a non-compact manifold have infinite-dimensional cohomology?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

For compact manifolds, Hodge Theory tells us that (de Rham) cohomology is finite dimensional. What about non-compact manifolds? That is:

> Can non-compact manifolds have infinite dimensional cohomology?

If the answer is yes, is there an example for which this is easy to see?

Comment: A  necessary condition is that the manifold must not admit a finite good cover

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The (non-compact) manifold $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Z^2$ should have infinite first homology and cohomology.

Answer (score 11):

Sure. Here are two examples:

1. Let $M$ be the real line with all integer points removed. Then $M$ is the disjoint union of countably many open intervals, and $H^0 (M, \mathbb{R})$ is a real vector space of uncountably infinite dimension. (To be precise, it is the dual of the real vector space of countably infinite dimension.)
2. Let $M$ be the real plane with the set $\{ (n, 0) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ removed. It's not too hard to see that $M$ is homotopy-equivalent to a chain of countably many circles joined side-by-side. It follows that $H^1 (M, \mathbb{R})$ is a real vector space of uncountably infinite dimension – we can concoct differential forms with a prescribed singularity at each hole independently, and their cohomology classes are distinct because they can be distinguished by integrating along a loop around the relevant singularities.

Comment: However the  last De Rham cohomology vanishes for non compact  manifold.

Comment: Interesting answer. Anyway I don't get why we have unconuntable dimension in 1. Shouldn't the zero cohomology group count the number of connected components? Does this hold only for the finite case ?

Comment: The 0th _homology_ group counts the number of connected components. The 0th _cohomology_ group counts the number of locally constant functions.